# How should I overload '<' in a map for this class?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have the class `tranzitie` and a  `map<int, map<tranzitie, int>>` . How should I overload the `<` operator for `tranzitie` in order for the map to work properly? It contains two chars and one string. I tried, but find() would't work well, considering values equal even though they weren't (in my perspective).

```
class tranzitie{
public:
    char litera;
    char top;
    string newst;

    bool operator==(const tranzitie& x);
    tranzitie& operator=(const tranzitie& x);
    tranzitie (const tranzitie& x);
    tranzitie(){};
    inline bool operator< (const tranzitie& rhs) const;
};
```

Comment: What have you tried,  what did you get, and what (**and why**)did you expect?

Comment: hint: You should use `std::tie`

Comment: how do you want them to be ordered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare all your data members:

```
 bool operator< (const tranzitie& rhs) const {
     if( litera == rhs.litera ) {
        if( top == rhs.top ) {
            return newst < rhs.newst;
        }
        return top < rhs.top;
     }
     return litera < rhs.litera;
 }
```

Comment: `if(litera!=rhs.litera)return litera<rhs.litera;   if (top!=rhs.top)return top<rhs.top;  return newst<rhs.newst;` avoids the nesting, and is far easier to read.

Comment: @MooingDuck my goal was to show how to writing the less operator for classes with several members. Nesting in that case is more readable as for me.

Comment: Really? I mean, readability is subjective, but mine is fewer lines, keeps the comparisons for each member together, avoids nesting, and has identical performance.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer implement `operator<` as a free function instead of a member function. If you need to access the private members inside the `operator<` function you should make the `operator<` function a friend. In your case it is not needed as the members of `tranzitie` are public.

The easiest pattern to memorize is probably this:

```
bool operator<(const tranzitie& lhs, const tranzitie& rhs) {
  if (lhs.litera < rhs.litera) return true;
  if (rhs.litera < lhs.litera) return false;
  if (lhs.top < rhs.top) return true;
  if (rhs.top < lhs.top) return false;
  return lhs.newst < rhs.newst;
}
```

The best pattern to memorize is probably this:

```
bool operator<(const tranzitie& lhs, const tranzitie& rhs) {
  return
    std::tie(lhs.litera, lhs.top, lhs.newst) <
    std::tie(rhs.litera, rhs.top, rhs.newst);
}
```